# Scrolling to top of list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

My jetpack compose app uses a `LazyColumn` to display data from history. When I am at the beginning of the `LazyColumn` and data is entered into the database, it will automatically be displayed on top with `scrollState.scrollToItem(0, 0)` each time. In this case, if I scroll down the list, exit the screen, and then return to it, then I will remain in the same place (at the bottom of the list). **I need to fix this so that every time I enter the screen, I end up at the beginning of the list (`LazyColumn`)**.

```
@Composable
fun HistoryTableList(
    viewModel: HistoryViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyColumn(
        state = scrollState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(
                HistoryListHorizontalPadding,
                0.dp,
                HistoryListHorizontalPadding,
                HistoryListPaddingBottom
            )
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        items(
            items = historyItems,
            key = { historyRecord ->
                historyRecord.uid
            }
        ) { historyRecord ->
            historyRecord?.let {
                viewModel.onListScrolled(scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset)

                if (scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex <= 1) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        scrollState.scrollToItem(0, 0)
                    }
                }

                HistoryTableItem(history = historyRecord)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you exiting the screen? If you remove `rememberLazyListState` from the view tree, it's not gonna save the state, check out how [this example](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/eca76e17d6fb8910c0447a3665b2c658) works

Comment: @PhilipDukhov i think, it's save the state, because default `LazyColumn` constructor has field `state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),`

Comment: It saves data between recompositions, but if `remember` is removed from the view tree, it frees the data. Otherwise it would lead to a fast memory overflow

Comment: @PhilipDukhov if i use `scrollState = LazyListState()` - i get the same behavior. When changing activity to another and then returning to history - I stay in the same place LazyColumn

Comment: @Sunbey13 Well if you are changing from one activity to another, then your screen is not being destroyed. While you can use multiple activities in any Android app, Compose was primarily designed to be used in single-activity apps. Perhaps you can terminate the activity before navigating to the other activity. Alternatively, call invalidate on your DataSource.